# Back Button issue in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I want back button at most of the view except few view. I have made back button like this:

```
<div class="row back">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="goBack()"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Back</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, Here is script.

```
<script>
    function goBack() {
        window.history.back();
    }
</script>
```

One way is to adding these to every view but I have more than 100 views so, It's tedious to add these to every page and If I need some changes later It will be difficult.

I have added these to master blade and try to remove html content using script on every page where I don't need back button like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('.back').css('display','none');
    });
</script>
```

Main Problem is this script works slowly and back button appears for some visible time i.e. when page is loading. How can I get out of this ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you add the style in `css`. adding in document ready this will wait until DOM is ready meaning button is there then it will hide

Comment: `$('.back').remove()` have same effect over there

Comment: Try putting the script in the `<head>` section.

Comment: Script to remove at head section ?

Comment: why did you tagged laravel?

Comment: Move the script inside the `<head>` and `</head>` tags. This will make the script load before loading the body of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're going with the approach of adding the back button to every view and then disabling it in some. You can do this.

```
@if (!isset($disableBackButton))
    <div class="row back">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right">
                <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="goBack()"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Back</span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Then add this to the views for which you do not want to show the back button.

```
{{ $disableBackButton = true }}
```

Comment: I thought `{{ $disableBackButton = true }}` assignment was disabled in blade syntax?

Comment: @ThomasMoors it assigns and echoes true, which we disregard. But it works.

Comment: @Sandeesh Ah ok!

Answer (score 1):

How about adding it to your master.blade.php file (or one that is used in all your views). And then you setup your controller so that it tells if you want a button or not. It would be something like this:

```
class pageController extends Controller{

    public function index(){
        return view()->make('pages.index')->with(['hideBackButton' => true]);
    }

}
```

and in your blade you can do:

```
@unless(isset($hideBackButton))

        <div class="row back">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="goBack()"><span><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Back</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

@endunless
```

Answer (score 1):

A better approach will be to create a separate layout as backBtn.blade.php and then include it in your views as

```
@include('backBtn')
```